# Add one space after every two characters and add a character infront of every single character

Tags: c#, string

I want to add one space after every two characters, and add a character in front of every single character.

This is my code:

```
string str2;
str2 = str1.ToCharArray().Aggregate("", (result, c) => result += ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && (result.Length + 1) % 3 == 0) ? " " : "") + c.ToString());
```

I have no problems separating every two characters with one space, but how do I know if the separated string has an individual character, and add a character infront of that character?

I understand that my question is confusing as I'm not sure how to put what I want in words..
So I'll just give an example:

I have this string:

```
0123457
```

After separating every two characters with a space, I'll get:

```
01 23 45 7
```

I want to add a 6 infront of the 7.

Note: Numbers are dependent on user's input, so it's not always the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Iterate across the characters in the input string and use a StringBuilder to build the desired output.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm quite new to this :/

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous. Do you mean: split your string into chunks of 2 characters, separate each pair with a space. If there's an odd character left over (at the end), prefix it with another (specific) character to make it into a final pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you asked for

```
string str1 = "3322356";
            string str2;

            str2 = String.Join(" ", 
                str1.ToCharArray().Aggregate("",
                (result, c) => result += ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) &&
                    (result.Length + 1) % 3 == 0) ? " " : "") + c.ToString())
                    .Split(' ').ToList().Select(
                x => x.Length == 1 
                    ? String.Format("{0}{1}", Int32.Parse(x) - 1, x) 
                    : x).ToArray());
```

result is "33 22 35 56"

Comment: Is this a serious suggestion?

Comment: Well.. it worked hahah.

edit: and thanks david, I'll look more into stringbuilder, seems pretty nice!

Comment: Why do you accept the joke answer? I mean I get the joke but this is not real code, it's just a bit of fun. Or do you really believe that all problems must be solved with Linq?

Answer (score 21):

```
[TestMethod]
public void StackOverflowQuestion()
{
    var input = "0123457";
    var temp = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.{2})", "$1 ");
    Assert.AreEqual("01 23 45 7", temp);
}
```

Comment: a TrimEnd(" ") is required. Anyway, great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
static string ProcessString(string input)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input.Length*3/2);
    for (int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((i>0) & (i%2==0))
            buffer.Append(" ");
        buffer.Append(input[i]);
    }
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Naturally you'd need to add in some logic about the extra numbers, but the basic idea should be clear from the above.

Comment: this way he could to the processing he wants

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try, if i right understand your request,

```
String.Length % 2
```

if result is 0, you done with first iteration, if not, just add a character infront of last one.