# C# Textbox insert space for every 2 characters entered

Tags: textbox

Is there a way to insert a space for every 2 characters entered in a textbox?

For example as a user enters the string 22F188, i would like it to appear as 22 F1 88 in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestMethod]
public void StackOverflowQuestion()
{
    var input = "0123457";
    var temp = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.{2})", "$1 ");
    Assert.AreEqual("01 23 45 7", temp);
}
```

Or

```
static string ProcessString(string input)
{
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input.Length*3/2);
    for (int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((i>0) & (i%2==0))
            buffer.Append(" ");
        buffer.Append(input[i]);
    }
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

[Add one space after every two characters and add a character infront of every single character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615748/add-one-space-after-every-two-characters-and-add-a-character-infront-of-every-si)

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyPressed event for this.

```
int i = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(i < 2){
        i++;
    }
    else{
        i = 0;
        textBox1.Text += ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i forgot to mention that this also applies if the text is pasted into the textbox